# Use iOS 7 swipe from left border in Navigation without Top Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I am currently working on an app that has two or more views and I want to swipe around between them. Right now I'm using a Navigation Controller.
Unfortunately if I use push to swipe to another view the transition is always from right to left. It used to be a problem that the swipe from left to right transition was not available.

With iOS 7 the transition from left to right (back) is working out of the box but the swipe gesture only works if you have the "Top Bar" activated.

Is there a way to keep the animation for my left to right swipe without displaying the top bar with the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out my self. You can simply enable the Top Bar and check "Hidden". Now the swipe back works with the right animation and there is still no Bar.